# Oracle: Analytic Function partitioned over nullable values

Tags: oracle

I DON't want to count NULL values. Because NULL should not be equal to NULL.

Look at this query result: [link](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/63341/des)

```
WITH temp as (
SELECT 'A' as master , 1 Col from dual
UNION SELECT 'A' , 3  from dual
UNION SELECT 'B' , 1 from dual
UNION SELECT 'B' , 2 from dual
UNION SELECT 'C' , 1 from dual
UNION SELECT NULL , 1 from dual
UNION SELECT NULL , 2 from dual)
SELECT
   master,
   count(Col) over (partition by master)
FROM
  temp
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to filter out the rows where `master` IS NULL, you can do something like

SELECT master,
       SUM( CASE WHEN master IS NULL 
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
             END) OVER (PARTITION BY master)
  FROM temp

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  WITH temp as (
  2  SELECT 'A' as master , 1 Col from dual
  3  UNION SELECT 'A' , 3  from dual
  4  UNION SELECT 'B' , 1 from dual
  5  UNION SELECT 'B' , 2 from dual
  6  UNION SELECT 'C' , 1 from dual
  7  UNION SELECT NULL , 1 from dual
  8  UNION SELECT NULL , 2 from dual)
  9  SELECT master,
 10         SUM( CASE WHEN master IS NULL
 11                   THEN 0
 12                   ELSE 1
 13               END) OVER (PARTITION BY master)
 14*   FROM temp
SQL> /

M SUM(CASEWHENMASTERISNULLTHEN0ELSE1END)OVER(PARTITIONBYMASTER)
- -------------------------------------------------------------
A                                                             2
A                                                             2
B                                                             2
B                                                             2
C                                                             1
                                                              0
                                                              0
```

Comment: Also, if `col` can be null, and you don't want those rows counted either, then `count(case when master is not null then col else null end) over (partition by master)` Note: `else null` is optional, sense the default if no conditions match is for `case` to return null.

Comment: And if you don't care about whether `col` is null or not, then just do `count(master) over (partition by master)`. Instead of Justin's `sum(case ....'

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, filter them out:

```
  1  WITH temp as (
  2  SELECT 'A' as master , 1 Col from dual
  3  UNION SELECT 'A' , 3  from dual
  4  UNION SELECT 'B' , 1 from dual
  5  UNION SELECT 'B' , 2 from dual
  6  UNION SELECT 'C' , 1 from dual
  7  UNION SELECT NULL , 1 from dual
  8  UNION SELECT NULL , 2 from dual)
  9  SELECT
 10     master,
 11     count(Col) over (partition by master)
 12  FROM
 13    temp
 14* WHERE master is not null
SQL> /

M COUNT(COL)OVER(PARTITIONBYMASTER)
- ---------------------------------
A                                 2
A                                 2
B                                 2
B                                 2
C                                 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Null isn't *equal* to null.  But from the perspective of aggregation, null is *equivalent* to null.  It's not the analytics that do that; it's the aggregation itself.

```
  1  WITH temp as (
  2  SELECT 'A' as master , 1 Col from dual
  3  UNION SELECT 'A' , 3 from dual
  4  UNION SELECT 'B' , 1 from dual
  5  UNION SELECT 'B' , 2 from dual
  6  UNION SELECT 'C' , 1 from dual
  7  UNION SELECT NULL , 1 from dual
  8  UNION SELECT NULL , 2  from dual )
  9  SELECT
 10     master,
 11     count(Col)
 12  FROM
 13*   temp group by master
SQL> /

M COUNT(COL)
- ----------
           2
A          2
B          2
C          1
```